# Xubuntu 19.10 - Display keeps defaulting to 3840x2160 after display restart

Tags: xubuntu, display, display-resolution

I've just installed Xubuntu 19.10 on an Acer Revo One RL85 and have an issue with the display resolution. (Ubuntu works fine incidentally)

I have it connected to a 47" Samsung 4K TV that will do 3840x2160 @ 30hz but I want 1920x1080 @ 60hz.

When i set 1920x1080 @ 60hz, it works perfectly, until I switch the TV off, which causes the desktop to display 1920x1080 but only in the top left quarter of the screen when switched back on.

I don't even know where to begin to troubleshoot this or resolve so any help would be gratefully received!